integrations by parts using semilinear differenial equation $-\Delta u=e^u$
This questions is from the paper stable solutions of $-\Delta u=e^u$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$ by Alberto Farina.
I don't understand the beginning of the proof. How to use the integration by parts to find that expression? 
I think that it use $-\Delta u=\nabla\cdot\nabla u$.
Proposition 
Assume $N \geq 2$ and let $\Omega$ be a domain (possibly unbounded) of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ be a stable solution of
$$
-\Delta u = e^u \quad \text{on } \Omega.
$$
Then, for any integer $m \geq 5$ and any $\alpha \in (0,2)$, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega} e^{(2\alpha+1)u} \psi^{2m} \leq \left( \frac{m}{2 - \alpha}\right)^{2\alpha+1} \int_{\Omega} \left( |\nabla \psi|^2 + |\psi||\Delta \psi| \right)^{2\alpha+1}
$$
for all test functions $\psi \in C^2_c(\Omega)$ satisfying $0 \leq \psi \leq 1$ in $\Omega$.
Proof.
For any $\varphi \in C^2_c(\Omega)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega} \left| \nabla \left( e^{\alpha u} \right) \right|^2 \varphi^2 = \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_{\Omega} e^{(2\alpha+1)u} \varphi^2 + \frac{1}{4} \int_{\Omega} e^{2\alpha u} \Delta (\varphi^2).
\end{equation*}
Multiply the equation $-\Delta u = e^u$ by $e^{2\alpha u} \varphi^2$ and integrate by parts to find
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \left( e^{2\alpha u} \right) \varphi^2 + \int_{\Omega} e^{2\alpha u} \nabla u \cdot \nabla (\varphi^2) = \int_{\Omega} e^{(2\alpha+1)u} \varphi^2.
$$
and therefore,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega}\nabla e^{(2\alpha +1)u} \varphi^2 = \frac{2}{\alpha} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla e^{\alpha u}|^2 \varphi^2 + \frac{1}{2\alpha}\int_{\Omega}\nabla e^{2\alpha u} \nabla(\varphi)^2 = \frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla e^{\alpha u}|^2 \varphi^2 - \frac{1}{2\alpha} \int_{\Omega}\nabla e^{2\alpha u}\Delta (\varphi^2) 
\end{equation}

This looks like one of Green's identities

So sometimes integration by parts means using Green´s identities?

Green’s identities are the generalization of integration by parts to higher dimensions

If you mean
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega} \left| \nabla \left( e^{\alpha u} \right) \right|^2 \varphi^2 = \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_{\Omega} e^{(2\alpha+1)u} \varphi^2 + \frac{1}{4} \int_{\Omega} e^{2\alpha u} \Delta (\varphi^2),
\end{equation*}
then @whpowell96 's hint is far from what is happening underneath. The major trick involved relates to Scharfetter-Gummel exponential fitting:
$$
\alpha\nabla u = e^{-\alpha u} \nabla (e^{\alpha u}).
$$
Note that there is no term involving gradient of the test function $\varphi^2$, then it is better to work from $\int_{\Omega} e^{2\alpha u} \Delta (\varphi^2)$ as follows, note all the boundary terms from integration by parts (or Green's formula) are omitted.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega} e^{2\alpha u} \Delta (\varphi^2) 
& = - \int_{\Omega} \nabla (e^{2\alpha u}) \cdot \nabla (\varphi^2)
\\
& = - \int_{\Omega} \nabla (e^{\alpha u} e^{\alpha u}) \cdot \nabla (\varphi^2)
\\
& = - 2\int_{\Omega} e^{\alpha u}\nabla ( e^{\alpha u}) \cdot \nabla 
(\varphi^2)
\\
&= 2\int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot \big(e^{\alpha u}\nabla ( e^{\alpha u}) \big) 
\varphi^2
\\
& = 2\int_{\Omega}  \big( \nabla (e^{\alpha u}) \cdot \nabla ( e^{\alpha u})
+ e^{\alpha u} \Delta (e^{\alpha u}) \big) 
\varphi^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
To simplify $e^{\alpha u} \Delta (e^{\alpha u})$ we can use that trick above, together with the PDE for the second term:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta  e^{\alpha u} & = \nabla\cdot(\nabla e^{\alpha u}) 
= \nabla\cdot( e^{\alpha u} \alpha \nabla u) 
\\
&= 
\color{red}{\alpha \nabla u} \cdot \nabla (e^{\alpha u} ) 
+ \alpha e^{\alpha u}\Delta u
\\
&= \color{red}{e^{-\alpha u} \nabla (e^{\alpha u})} \cdot \nabla (e^{\alpha u} ) 
- \alpha e^{\alpha u} e^u.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{\alpha u} \Delta (e^{\alpha u}) = \nabla (e^{\alpha u})\cdot \nabla (e^{\alpha u}) - \alpha e^{(2\alpha+1)u},
$$
and the identity is shown.

You are correct that more is needed to prove the rest of the statement. I was clarifying Green’s identity as OP seemed confused on what integration by parts meant in this context

because of academic paper never mentioned Scharfetter-Gummel exponential fitting, it is very difficult for me to know that i have to use it. In fact, I don't remember ever seeing this before.  But thank you for the answer. @Shuhao Cao

@Richard NO worries, it is a common trick when there are exponentials of $u$ involved, or one wants to convert the convection into a "positive" term, and I happened to have worked on things that use this trick.
